# Right way to scrape this noisy price tag

Tags: regex, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Given a `<div>` containing a price with a lot of noise:

```
Price 1\u00a0500\u00a0000 EUR
```

and you want only the pure amount (1500000), what is the best way to implement this in Scrapy?

I tried to combine regex:

```
il.add_css('price', 'div.price_tag::text', re='([.\d]+)\s*(?:EUR)')
```

together with a general pipeline removing non-ascii code:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    def remove_non_ascii(text):
        return ''.join(i for i in text if ord(i)<128)
    for key, value in item.items():
        item[key] =remove_non_ascii(item[key]) 
    return item
```

But it seems the pipeline is executed after the regex, and hence it would only find "000" instead of "1500000".

Of course one could build in a `.replace()` somewhere for those specific cases, but I would prefer to stick with the standard methods available and keep it better maintainable.

Comment: Thanks, this throws error `nothing to repeat at position 1`. I also tried on a different environment with `re.findall(r'(*UCP)\d+(?:\s\d+)*(?=\s*EUR)', 'Price 1\u00a0500\u00a0000 EUR')`.

Comment: Ah,  it is Python, sorry. Of course remove `(*UCP)` that is just redundant in all senses here, try `\d+(?:\s\d+)*(?=\s*EUR)`

Comment: Thanks, getting closer, but it still does not remove the NO-BREAK SPACE: `1\xa0500\xa0000` I really should refresh my regex fluency..

Comment: Of course. You can't remove anything while matching. It is impossible.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for confirming! But this can now be combined with the pipeline idea and remove the spaces. Thanks. If you post the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\d+(?:\s\d+)*(?=\s*EUR)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bwlsou/1).

**Details**:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\s\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of a whitespace and one or more digits
- `(?=\s*EUR)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location in string that is immediately followed with zero or more whitespaces and then `EUR`.

**NOTE** that `\s` and other shorthand character classes are Unicode-aware by default in a Python 3.x regex, you need no additional flags.

Comment: Thanks, together with the pipeline getting rid of whitespace within the price is answering this question.